# Emergency flight to Madrid in 3 days & US Passport just expired

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality

I am a US Citizen, and I need to travel to Spain in a few days but my passport is recently expired. I have dual citizenship to Ireland and hold a valid Irish passport that states my birthplace is the US on it. Would I be able to travel on this Irish passport while also brining my expired one with me as proof. I read that as of last month you can travel back into the United States on a expired passport until December. Will this work for me?

Comment: You can get a US passport renewed in 3 business days. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You should be able to get into Spain with your Irish passport.

You can return to the US with an expired passport if you return before the end of the year. https://www.state.gov/return-travel-on-recently-expired-u-s-passports/

Before you book: I strongly recommend that you contact the airline and verify that they will let you board the return flight with an expired US passport. Otherwise try a different airline.

To verify put all your info in here:

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to enter Spain on an Irish passport anyway? Both are EU countries, so your right to enter Spain is a fundamental right.

Comment: There is also a very remote possibility of getting checked by CBP on leaving the US, in which case I don't know if they would deny exit of a US citizen who doesn't have a valid US passport.

Comment: @MSalters: I've entered the EU with both my US or my EU passport. Makes no difference.

Comment: @Hilmar Have you been checked on US exit by CBP? If so, was your US passport valid or expired?

Comment: In 100s of international trips I have NEVER been been exit checked in the US. Nor have I evert witnessed or even heard (credible first hand account) about an exit check. This seems to be extremely rare and it's relevance to normal travel feels blown way out of proportion.  Feels similar to "can they check your electronic devices on entry". Yes they can and it happens, but it's extremely rare and only happens if there already something fishy going out. It's just not worth  worrying about it. Traffic jam or flat tire are much higher risks

Comment: @Hilmar there's a contributor on flyertalk who says (credibly, in my opinion) that the checks are very common on certain routes that are associated with money laundering.

Comment: @phoog. Thanks. Would you  mind posting a link? I'm curious how this actually works and also about the legal aspect. The CBP can't deny entry to a citizen (with or without passport), can they deny exit ?